# Sentence about habit

Tags: grammar

When we have a habit of doing something, how do we make a sentence?
He is habitual of drinking alcohol.
Does it sound fine?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a specific verb tense that *implies* a habit, the simple present.
*Context* plays an important role in this implied meaning, but on their own these sentences would certainly convey the idea that someone has a drinking habit:

> He drinks a lot.
>   He is a heavy drinker.
>   or even
>   He drinks.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the following:

- He habitually drinks alcohol.
- He is in the habit of drinking alcohol.
- He has an alcohol habit. (Slightly unusual to use for this specific example, but still correct English.)

Or if it’s more than a simple habit, and considered a problem:

- He’s an alcoholic.

Answer (score 0):

No the standard form is he has a drinking habit, or he has a habit of drinking. The latter being more kind while the former indicates alcohol abuse. And if that's the case one would simply say "he's an alcoholic". https://www.aa.org

Comment: Perhaps, but the question is more generic and not about drinking in particular.

Answer (score 0):

"in the habit of," "habituated to":

He is in the habit of (or is habituated to) drinking alcohol.